# /usr/bin/snap disappeared suddenly

Tags: snap

I had some applications installed via snap that were running perfectly until today.

When I started my computer I was not able to launch them.

These applications still show on my apps list but clicking on one doesn't launch it.

Also trying to start them via terminal results in a `command not found` error, even thought my shell suggests the command.

Another thing is that the applications still exist in `~/snap` and `/snap` but in the second directory they link to `/usr/bin/snap` which seems to have vanished.

I can't use the `snap` command anymore.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and didn't do any update before the issue, and after getting that problem I updated but nothing changed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you do `sudo apt install snapd`? This should reinstall the `/usr/bin/snap` executable.

Comment: @Jos, thanks it worked fine ! Any idea why `/usr/bin/snap` disappeared ?

Comment: No idea. Perhaps you can take a look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see if it turns up anything.

Comment: @Jos, indeed `snapd` has been removed yesterday when I did `apt-get remove openssh-client openssh-server` because I was having some issues with ssh. But installing these two packages again didn't bring back snapd. thank you for the tip !

Comment: Please move solution to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, uninstalling either `openssh-client` or `openssh-server` removes `snapd` but doesn't install it back after the reinstall. So I had to reinstall `snapd` manually with `sudo apt install snapd`.
Thanks to [@Jos](https://askubuntu.com/users/149708/jos).